# How to manipulate config/config.php.inc under mac 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, postgresql, phppgadmin

I would like to change the setting of config.php.inc and incldude  $conf['plugins'] = array('DBDesigner'); That is a plugin for the phpPgadmin in order to use the database designer as noted here:
https://github.com/diorman/DBDesigner
and this is how it should look like
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9tIl3zB9Ro

However I cant find the config/config.php.inc under phpPgadmin I spent already so much time but there isnt such a folder. I installed phpPGadmin from the postgreSQL stack builder. Could someone provide a solution....Thanks

Comment: This is EnterpriseDB, not standard Postgres, right? That's definitely worth mentioning...

Comment: Yes, its EnterpriseDB

Comment: In windows there is a directory C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\phpPgAdmin\conf to manipulate that file but not in mac

Comment: maybe by using terminal?

Comment: This seems to explain where/how to create the config.php.inc file on OSX: https://bmark.us/bmark/readable/e3f9423d306258